# How to correctly manage thousands of ETL replication objects

Tags: airflow, etl, mwaa

How can I efficiently manage the replication of thousands of objects from Salesforce in MWAA using separate DAGs per object, prioritizing some objects over others and avoiding restarting the entire process in case of failure?

Context: I want to replicate a large number of objects from Salesforce to MWAA using Airflow, but some objects are small and can be processed quickly, while others are larger and require more time. I need to ensure that in case of failure, the process does not start from the beginning and I can prioritize certain objects to be replicated first. I am considering using separate DAGs for each object, but I am new to this approach and would appreciate any advice.